# iOS XMPP disconnect on background doesn't get reported

Tags: ios, xmpp, disconnect

When the app is in the background and xmpp disconnects because the internet goes down, and if the internet comes back up, when I open the app, the disconnect call is not made so the app doesn't try to reconnect.

If i check the xmppstream is connected it shows as Yes. How can I check if the connection is still alive when I go back to the app?

Currently I am trying a disconnect, and connect each time the app wakes up. But ideal would be to detect disconnection...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can detect when the app wakes up, then send a [ping](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html).  If you don't get a reply, reconnect.  If the XMPP lib you use has support for [Stream Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html), especially the stream resumption support, you could use that to pick up the stream.

A better solution would be to have a separate daemon that manages the connection, and stays alive in the background, if that's even allowed on iOS.  Also, [this XEP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0286.html) might be of interest.

Comment: As a side not, if the server does not support ping, it will just reply with a harmless warning (ejabberd does this, IIRC), and you still determine if the connection has died or not.

Comment: Can you please give idea about how can we keep session alive in background mode?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using XMPPFramework (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework), then take a look at XMPPReconnect, which will save you a lot of the hassle of reconnecting.

After the stream has been created, use the following.

```
xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
[xmppReconnect activate:xmppStream];
[xmppReconnect addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Comment: can i put in this in "setupStream" or other where ?